# Showing global temperature data in Leaflet layers by GRIB2 files?

Tags: leaflet, grib-2

Wind data already shown in map by [danwild/leaflet-velocity](https://github.com/danwild/leaflet-velocity.)

Now I want add temperature to map by tiles.

How can I convert GRIB2 files to tiles?

Comment: This might be of help (possible duplicate): https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19543/how-to-process-grib2-data-for-visualization

Comment: Thanks for recommending. I'm afraid that dosen't work for me.The introduction of wgrib2 showing  `export to ieee, text, binary, CSV, netcdf and mysql`, none tiles.

Comment: I was thinking of solution described in question, namely `gdal_translate`: https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/grib.html